# Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/testing'

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-cdk

i'm trying to work with the `createKeyboardEvent` in `@angular/cdk/testing` in order to be able to use the key board events:

```
const ENTER_EVENT = createKeyboardEvent('keydown', ENTER, inputNativeElement);
```

I couldn’t find the module at all even though i install `@angular/cdk` with :

```
  `npm i @angular/cdk`
```

Comment: Right now, the testing utilities are intentionally not exposed in the public API.

At some point there was the idea of exposing those utilities to the public using a secondary entry-point (similar as for `@angular/core/testing`) See this:https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5803#issuecomment-323211124

Comment: @nircraft so there is no other solution or something to exchange it with?

Comment: not that i know of.

Comment: Assuming you have `inputDebugElement` pointing to the same element as DebugElement, Try this: `inputDebugElement.triggerEventHandler('keydown.enter', {});`

Answer (score 2):

This was an internal module as you can see in this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5803#issuecomment-323211124), but now with the new component harnesses at angular 9 they opened it up to everyone use.

You can install it with

```sh
npm install @angular/cdk --save
```

and import it with

```js
import {ComponentHarness} from '@angular/cdk/testing';
```

Answer (score -1):

**There is no module @angular/cdk/testing, it has been removed and issue stil holds on github.**